# Question is genuine.. But I feel it is spamming

Tags: discussion, support, bug

Here is the question :  [localhost/private-sales what is the path to edit the default information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86230/localhost-private-sales-what-is-the-path-to-edit-the-default-information).

This question got 4 Upvotes, 2 Favorites within 1 minute !! But I can confirm there were only 2 views at that time (I reloaded the page after 1 min).

**My question is :**

- How is this even possible !! ??
- Whether we need to close this question ?

Comment: i am also still confused about this question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed looks a bit odd, but it does not look like spam to me.
The screenshot is taken from the localhost, there is no link to something "spammy" mentioned, and not even an extension name.
Looks like a valid question to me.

Comment: yes question is valid which I have already mentioned in the question. What I feel "spammy" is the upvotes &favs that got. I think that need to be review

Comment: I don't have access to see who voted for this (and I shouldn't)  and there is nothing in the suspicious vote patterns report.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy i have seen the Sportee website question Couple of times these are 3-4 guys working on the site the fav and upvote each other question ,i have noticed it sevral times

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar this is really an offense. I just flagged them right now, since I spotted more such activities now. Thanks for pointing out this. How do you know Sportee website developers are involving in this spamming ? It would be great if you can provide some proofs, if possible.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy here is another sportee dev , http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/29582/akshata-v-s look her each question has on an average 4-5 upvotes even if they are not that good